# Cassandra limit 1 vs LINQ First()

Tags: c#, linq, cassandra

I am new to `cassandra`, so I would like to know what's the impact of using `limit` option in `cassandra` queries. I would like to get one row with specific value in one column. What  is better to use:

- `Cassandra` query with *where* clause and option *`limit 1`*
- `Cassandra` query which returns a list of rows and use LINQ `First(x=>x.value=="value")`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The LINQ clause First() translates to LIMIT 1 when generating CQL statements, so from performance point of view the two approaches are (almost) identical.

The LINQ interface of the driver basically generates CQL statements and executes them.

Just for reference, here is the class that deals with code generation:
https://github.com/datastax/csharp-driver/blob/master/src/Cassandra/Data/Linq/CqlExpressionVisitor.cs
Search for "First" and you will see, that _limit is set to 1.